# Assigning and passing a reference variable in function

Tags: php, function, variables, reference

```
function test(&$a)
{
    $a = $a + 3;

}
```

If I assign the variable first and call it:
$a = 3;
test($a);
echo $a; //it will output 6

but if I do this
test($a = 3);
echo $a; //it will return 3

Why is that? Doesnt' the reference variable in the second function call modify it to be 6 as well?

Comment: This behaviour is clearly documented in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (see that last example). In a nutshell, `$a = 3` is an *expression*, not a variable, so no this does not work. If you crank error reporting up [this produces a Strict Standards error](http://codepad.org/jhxs8H10).

Comment: Don't use references, unless you explicitely want it's "in-out"-behaviour. In your case the muuuch cleaner solution is a simple `function test($a) { return $a+3; }; $a = test($a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on strict standards to see:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

You should not expect your second example to work at all.  The fact that it does seems to be a coincidence, though PHP does document it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function test(&$a)
{
    echo $a;
    $a = $a + 3;
}

test($q = 3);
?>
```

This outputs `3`. I'm a bit surprised there, I expected to see `true` as `$q = 3` will usually succeed and thus return true.

Comment: $q = 3 when used as an expression in this way will return 3 (the value assigned to $q), not a TRUE or FALSE (unless you were actually assigning a boolean value). The value passed to the function isn't passed by reference because it isn't a variable; but the result of the expression, but the result of the expression (the value 3) is still passed to the function; hence the echo statement displays 3. $a is then treated as a local variable in the function, and assigned the value passed in (3).

Comment: I figured, I just thought it would work like `$x = mysql_fetch_array($record)` does (which is deprecated, I know). Learned something new today :)